# AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: python-3.x, singly-linked-list

I don't understand what is wrong with my code. it says

> AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'head'

Here is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
```

I created an empty linked list and added nodes:

```
class LinkedList():
    def __int__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insert(self, newNode):
        if self.head is None:
          self.head = newNode
        else:
            #head =>john->Ben->Matthew->None
            lastNode = self.head
            while True:
                if lastNode.next is None:
                    break
                lastNode = lastNode.next
            lastNode.next = newNode

    def printList(self):
        #head=>john->Ben->Matthew->None
        currentNode = self.head
        while True:
            if currentNode is None:
                break
            print(currentNode.data)
        currentNode = currentNode.next
    

# node => data, next
#firstnode.data => data, firstnode.next => None
firstNode = Node('john')
linkedlist = LinkedList()
linkedlist.insert(firstNode)
secondNode = Node('Ben')
linkedlist.insert(secondNode)
thridNode = Node('Matthew')
linkedlist.insert
linkedlist.printList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors which you could easily spot with some debugging (stepping through the code):

- The `LinkedList` function `__int__` is never executed (you could spot this by putting a breakpoint there). It should be named `__init__`.
- The main program does not add the third node, because it does not *call* the `insert` method -- it merely references it. You could spot this easily when stepping through the code, one instruction at a time, with a debugger. Add the parentheses and pass the argument.
- The `printList` has a loop that runs infinitely, because the line that moves the `currentNode` reference is not part of the loop's body. You could spot this easily again by stepping through the code with a debugger. This statement should be indented more to become part of the loop.

This should fix your problems.

Note: this was just a matter of debugging. You really can do this yourself in a good programming environment.